# Scanning a specific line in file in C

Tags: c, file, structure

I have a simple program that takes a value from file and displays it on screen. However, my structure doesn't seem to be working, since it always plugs out the first value in file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert(void);

int lineNum;

FILE *fPresDr;

struct store09
{
    char defPsDr[16];
}stock09[16];


int main()
{
    printf("Type the line number you want to view");
    scanf("%d",&lineNum);
    insert();
    printf("\n\nThe value in file is: %s",stock09[lineNum].defPsDr);
    getch();
}


void insert(void)
{
     fPresDr=fopen("TIRpresD.txt","r");
     fscanf(fPresDr,"%127[^\n]%*c",stock09[lineNum].defPsDr);
     fclose(fPresDr);
}
```

Example file:

```
two
seven
four
eleven
```

Input: "3" . Expected output: "four" . Real output: "two"

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). Check result of `scanf` & `fscanf`

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a simple fix?

Comment: Hint: You are not reading your file correctly. Search on Google, how to read a file using `fscanf`.

Comment: Using the debugger is a mandatory developer's skill. And don't expect us to do your work! Read also documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was expecting maybe an extra line that makes it work.

Comment: `"%127[^\n]%*c"` --> `"%15[^\n]%*c"` and use loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY a loop?, Where?

Comment: at insert() You must run the repeat `fscanf(fPresDr,"%15[^\n]%*c",stock09[index++].defPsDr);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fscanf` seems not only like overkill, but platform-dependent.  Why not just call `readline` enough times to get the line you want?

Comment: You mean make a do while loop around lineNum? , i suppose i could do that